# Symfony3 - form - multi-select with embed values

Tags: forms, symfony, nested

I made a little model: like

```
apps{
  // ONE TO MAY
  public pages  
}
```

I create fixtures to say:
app1 have 3 pages: page1, page2, page3
app2 have 3 pages: pagex, pagey, pagez

I would like to generate a form with value depending i mean a kind of form like this :

```
[ ] APP1
    [ ] page1
    [ ] page2
    [ ] page3
[ ] APP2
    [ ] pagex
    [ ] pagey
    [ ] pagez
```

I don't know how to do this easily without making twig check on entity,
I m sure it is possible with subquery in form, but can't find a post about it.

Any help is helpfull ;)

Good day !

Comment: What kind of form is it? Checkboxes? What does it represent?

Comment: it's check boxes multi select with logic parent/child hierarchy. it represents a kind of configuration for access user